# AJAX AutoComplete Extender - set ContextKey Paramerter-value & pass it to WebMethod along with the prefixText

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

after learning about the AutoComplete Attribute - `ContextKey`

i am using it as an advantage :

the data source of every extender object will be handled by same WebMethod.

that by it self, is an achivement for me .

now that every thing is allmost perfect, the problem is:

I need to pass another parameter, when request for AutoComplete-Datasource is sent by the Second Textbox, right after the stage = table was selected .

so now i need , not only the hardcoded/constant, but also the value of the selected table.

which is actually the value of `#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage`, along with the hardcoded `ContextKey` value...

(something like `ContextKey += value of TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage`)

so i could then be able to draw the specified Columns list by requested  table (the table's name)

this is ***`Jquery` Code***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('document').ready(function () {

       var IvalidValue_Msg = "table was not selected";
       var TBX_tables = $(this);

       var TBX_Columns = $('#TBX_ColumnsSelectorFirstStage');


       $('#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage')
       .val("Choose a Table")
       .focus(function () {

           $(this).val("");
           $(this).attr("dir", "ltr");

       }).blur(function () {
           var TBXTablsVALUE = $('#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage').val();
           var Lngth = $('#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage').val().length;
           var InvalidTBXBlur_TablesValue = TBXTablsVALUE == "" || TBXTablsVALUE == " " || Lngth < 4;
           if (InvalidTBXBlur_TablesValue) {
               $(this).focus();
               $(this).val(IvalidValue_Msg);
           }
           else {

               $(TBX_Columns).focus();
               SetContextKeyValue();
           }
           //$(this).next(':input').focus();

       }).change(function () {
           var TBXTablsVALUE = $('#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage').val();
           var Lngth = $('#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage').val().length;
           var InvalidTBXBlur_TablesValue = TBXTablsVALUE == "" || TBXTablsVALUE == " " || Lngth < 4;

           if (InvalidTableValue) {
               $(this).val(IvalidValue_Msg);
           }
           else {
               SetContextKeyValue();
           }
       }).click(function () {


               $(this).val("");

       });
   });
        /// ==========================================================\\\
       ///Jquery Section That Is Suppose To manipulate contextKey Property.

       function SetContextKeyValue() {
     //  var ttt = $get('AjaxAcEx_Columns_FirstStage',
       alert("asasas");
       // var x = $('#AutoCompleteExtender3'); //.set_contextKey($get('AjaxAcEx_Tables_FirstStage').value);
       alert($('#AjaxAcEx_Columns_FirstStage').attr("id")); 
   }
```

this is the ***ASPX Code***

```aspx
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolKitScrptMan1" runat="server"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>

<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" TargetControlID="TBX_FntsAC" runat="server"
                         MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="100" 
                         ServiceMethod="MyAcReqHandler" ContextKey="acFontsRquest"
                         FirstRowSelected="true" CompletionListCssClass="CL_Css_DataBase" CompletionListItemCssClass="CL_ItemCss_DataBase" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="CL_tHighlightedItemCss_DataBase">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender2" BehaviorID="AjaxAcEx_Tables_FirstStage" TargetControlID="TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage" runat="server"
                         MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="100"
                         ServiceMethod="MyAcReqHandler" ContextKey="acTablesSelector_FirstStage"
                         FirstRowSelected="true" CompletionListCssClass="CL_Css_DataBase" CompletionListItemCssClass="CL_ItemCss_DataBase" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="CL_tHighlightedItemCss_DataBase">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>


<%--  Here is where i am stuck .
     object /element -  AutoCompleteExtender3 / BehaviorID AjaxAcEx_Columns_FirstStage
    This is the object i need to Set it's ContextKey attribute-value,
     with the result value of #TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage
--%>

<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender3" BehaviorID="AjaxAcEx_Columns_FirstStage" TargetControlID="TBX_ColumnsSelectorFirstSTage" runat="server"
                         MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="100"
                         ServiceMethod="MyAcReqHandler" ContextKey="acColumnsSelector_FirstStage"
                         FirstRowSelected="true" CompletionListCssClass="CL_Css_DataBase" CompletionListItemCssClass="CL_ItemCss_DataBase" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="CL_tHighlightedItemCss_DataBase">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>


<div id="Div_firstStage" runat="server" style="width:90%" dir="rtl">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage"  runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TBX_ColumnsSelectorFirstStage" runat="server" />   

</div>
```

*** .Cs Code Behind*** (webMethod)

```aspx
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

public static List<string> MyAcReqHandler(string prefixText, string contextKey)
{

    List<string> retListAC = new List<string>();
    switch (contextKey)
    {

        case AutoComplete.Param.acTablesSelector_FirstStage:
            retListAC = GetListForAutoComplete<HTDB_Tables>(App.VarNms.SesDbTablsList);
            break;
        case AutoComplete.Param.acColumnsSelector_FirstStage:
            retListAC = GetListForAutoComplete<HTDB_Cols>(App.VarNms.SesDbTablsList);
            break;
        case AutoComplete.Param.acFontsRquest_SecondStage:
            retListAC = GetListForAutoComplete<fntNams>(App.VarNms.SesFontsList);
            break;

    }

    return AutoComplete.FromListStr(prefixText, retListAC);
}



private static List<string> GetListForAutoComplete<TheClassNameHere>(string SessionVarName, string NestedClassName="")
{
    List<string> ReturnedList = new List<string>();
    if (CurrSesVarSet.SesVar_AcDsListStr.Count == 0)
    {
        bool isNested = typeof(TheClassNameHere).IsNested;
        switch (isNested)
        {
            case true:
                ReturnedList = RflectMeths.anyNestedClassFldsAsListByType<TheClassNameHere>(NestedClassName);
                break;
            default:
                ReturnedList = RflectMeths.anyClassFldsAsListByType<TheClassNameHere>();
                break;
        }



        CurrSesVarSet.SesVar_AcDsListStr = ReturnedList;
        CurrentSession.AddVar(SessionVarName, ReturnedList);
    }
    else
        if (CurSessionMesthods.VarExistStat(App.VarNms.SesFontsList))
             ReturnedList = CurSessionMesthods.GetSessionVar.AsListStr(SessionVarName);
        else ReturnedList = CurrSesVarSet.SesVar_AcDsListStr;
    return ReturnedList;
}
```

as one of the efforts in this application was  to **avoid full post back** ,  I would like to implement - setting the `ContextKey`, via `Jquery` , ... **unless** I am wrong with my base assumption, that doing it through c# - code behind will result in a full page post back , so if it's done without a page reload i should not care as long as i coud get this parameter sent, as until now I have maintained a desktop like user experience (;

thanks for your help, solving this will be really appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

i have searched a lot for this answer , as i could not find any information on this implementation I guess I had to work harder , so as i can remember someone told me something about sports , you have to do it win this contest ,  so start as fast as you can and then accelerate , so as much as it was looking hard to find out i just worked a little more .

so what I was missing and as i lack of minimal experience with Jquery

one thing i did find in the internet is the function that is available  for setting the ContextKey 
so as I was too busy trying and get help (ready made code example that fits exactly to my scenario)
eventually with some more trial and error , I had to think that if there is a set . there must be a get (:

so this is how you can manipulate the existing key and concatenate it with anything else you want

```
   $('document').ready(function () {
       var IvalidValue_Msg = "table was not selected";
       var TBX_tables = $(this);
       var TstTBXCLS = $(this).next();
       var TBX_Columns = $('#TBX_ColumnsSelectorFirstStage');


       $('#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage')
       .val("Choose a Table")
       .focus(function () {

           $(this).val("");
           $(this).attr("dir", "ltr");

       }).blur(function () {
           var TBXTablsVALUE = $('#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage').val();
           var Lngth = $('#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage').val().length;
           var InvalidTBXBlur_TablesValue = TBXTBLSVALUE == "" || TBXTBLSVALUE == " " || Lngth < 4;
           if (InvalidTBXBlur_TablesValue) {
               $(this).focus();
               $(this).val(IvalidValue_Msg);
           }
           else {

               $(TBX_Columns).focus();
               SetContextKeyValue();
           }
           //$(this).next(':input').focus();

       }).change(function () {
           var TBXTablsVALUE = $('#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage').val();
           var Lngth = $('#TBX_TableSelectorFirstStage').val().length;
           var InvalidTBXBlur_TablesValue = TBXTBLSVALUE == "" || TBXTBLSVALUE == " " || Lngth < 4;

           if (InvalidTableValue) {
               $(this).val(IvalidValue_Msg);
           }
           else {
               SetContextKeyValue(TBXTBLSVALUE );
           }
       }).click(function () {


               $(this).val("");

       });
   });

       function SetContextKeyValue(selectedTableName) {

           var CurrentConextKey = $find('AjaxAcEx_Columns_FirstStage').get_contextKey();
           var JointParams = CurrentConextKey + "_" + selectedTableName;
           $find('AjaxAcEx_Columns_FirstStage').set_contextKey(JointParams);
           alert(JointParams);

   }
```

then in c# code behind just use `string.Split('_')`, to get them both, each  into a c# variable.
i hope this will help somone else with same use case, as example are not really easy to find.